# Javascript function decorator design pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, decorator

Is there any design pattern I can implement a decorator in Javascript?

Let's say I have a `user` object, with a `is_authenticated` property.

```
var user = {
    is_authenticated: true,
    name: 'Peter Parker'
}
```

In Python I would create a decorator to return the property `is_authenticated` and only run the function commands if that decorator returned truly, like this:

```
function userIsAuthenticated() {
    return user.is_authenticated;
}

@userIsAuthenticated
function say(message) {
    console.log(message + '\nSays ' user.name + '.');
}
```

Is Javascript I have to check if the user is authenticated before running anything inside the function.

```
function say(message) {
    if (user.is_authenticated) {
        console.log(message + '\nSays ' user.name + '.');
    }
}
```

How can I do any *decorator-like* is Js?
I thought about `binding` the function in its creation

```
function say(message) {
    this && (function(){
        console.log(message + '\nSays ' user.name + '.');
    }());
}.bind(user.is_authenticated);
```

But that way you lose the instance (`this` is now true/false) and also more characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it, and let `is_authentificated` return a new function:

```
function userIsAuthenticated(fn) {
    return function() {
        if (user.is_authenticated)
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

You can decorate arbitrary functions with it:

```
var say = userIsAuthenticated(function say(message) {
    console.log(message + '\nSays ' + user.name + '.');
});
```

Comment: I don't if you can call that a "design pattern". It's a just an [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) pattern, and with JavaScript's functional nature composing functions (using closure in this case) is trivial :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well in ES2016 you can use the same decorator pattern that python does. I've created a module that let you easily wrap your original code with your own.

https://github.com/cmartin81/decorator-wrap

Comment: Yeah, transpiling ES7 decorators is the way to go.